# Max length a USB-C charge cable can be for a Mac Mini 2018?

Tags: usb, mac-mini, power

The cables from Apple come in only a 1 and 2 meter length. Can you use longer and still power the Mac Mini 2018 properly?

The Mac Mini 2018 according to the Apple website and AppleCare uses a
USB-C Charge Cable that is connected to a USB-C Power Adapter:

https://www.apple.com/shop/mac/mac-accessories/power-cables?page=1&f=macmini_thdblt3_late2018&fh=4595%2B4a95

Comment: USB-C does, generally have a max cable length. And **very generally** 2 meters is the max length (there are exceptions). But as @BMike said a Mac Mini is not powered by USB-C.

Comment: I think the Apple Store is just indicating that the Mini can use these cables -- possibly to power other devices, like iPhones.

Comment: Since USB 2.0 is used to negotiate USB power delivery that puts a limit on what are often considered "charge only" cables.  Considered such even though they can work fine for more than charging but it sets customer expectations low and therefore minimizes complaints when they don't get 5 Gbps.  USB 2.0 is limited to 5 meters but finding such cables will be difficult as few bother to sell them, a 3 meter cable should not be too hard to find.  There are longer USB cables but they have a "repeater" in the middle to boost the signal and such, which means they are not truly a cable but a device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No USB-C cable powers a Mac mini properly. USB is direct current, low voltage.

[image]
Mini operates from mains power of 110 or 220 VAC.

Comment: What year model is this Mac Mini?

Comment: Then the Apple website is incorrect. Because it showed the USB-C charger. OK, thanks.

Comment: No Mac mini has ever been powered by USB. The unibody 2010 and newer take the same power cord. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini I don’t think you can blame Apple web site for an honest mistake, @EdwardCoast maybe with Apple silicon, a mini type Mac could exist on DC power in. Mains power is still very probable, though so the mini can provide a lot of power out over thunderbolt and USB-C

Comment: I'm more surprised, cause I've never seen a mistake on the Apple website. I'm glad I checked here about it, because I would have ordered the wrong thing. Thanks!

Comment: @EdwardCoast - Great catch! Phew. http://monoprice.com has great value and quality power cords. Ones that fit Mac mini can be $2 range as they are commodity connectors on both ends and used in printers and many portables. Safe, correct cables from third party can be very economical if you don’t want Apple parts and service and first party cables for Mac mini.